# Update current time and date if a column value changed to predefined text

Tags: excel

I want a column to add current time if A specific column have some predefined text.

In a cell of B column I have written a formula that update time in the basis of column A text.

```
=IF(A2="resolved",=NOW(),"not done")
```

This shows an error.

I want to apply this formula for Entire Column. I tied:

```
=IF(A2="resolved",NOW(),"not done")
```

but all time in Column B gets updated to same value if any cell is changed in A column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timestamping and copying a line to another sheet, if certain condition met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701395/timestamping-and-copying-a-line-to-another-sheet-if-certain-condition-met/29730272#29730272).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the worksheet set to auto calculate. So any time the condition was previously true, or for any cells in column A which currently match the condition, this will cause the current time stamp to be used.

The only way to prevent it from changing any cells matching the condition is to change it to manual calculation, then you would have to select a cell and press enter to perform the calculation. Unfortunately this would disable automatic calculation for the entire workbook, so all your other formulas would not update either. Unfortunately there is no way to do this on a cell by cell basis, other then to use vba, which could trigger only if certain cells are changed.